# Remove source references comment from .po file

Tags: poedit

I want to remove source references comment from `.po` file that is generated using poeditor.

Exa.

```
#: controllers/admin/device.php:282
msgid "Error while deleting !!"
msgstr "Error while deleting !!"
```

I want to remove this `#:` comments from `.po` file

Answer (score 3):

I got an answer:

https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/xgettext-Invocation.html

Check this link and i need to use `xgettext` with `--no-location` attribute

If you want it in `Windows` then refer this link:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#gettext-on-windows

And then using CMD and using this command you can acheive this:

```
xgettext --no-location -o /output-file-path /input-file-path
```

Comment: You can also use `--no-location` with `msgmerge`

Answer (score 1):

The following command does not require installing *xgettext* utility, rather it relies on *sed* utility that is pre-installed on UNIX-based systems:

```sh
sed -i '/#:.*$/d' *.po
```

On Windows this command can be executed through bash emulators like *Git Bash*